# is it possible to update a variable inside an if else statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I have to make a basic guessing game and I'm having some problems in this piece of code i am trying to assign a random number generated by a different method to the variable secretNumber however when i run this code the variable is not saved it simply prints out the variable and for gets it if i add another print statement outside of the if else statement it states that the variable has not been initialized. Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int secretNumber, playerGuess;
    String difficulty;
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please select your difficulty");
    System.out.println("E = easy M = medium, H = hard");
    difficulty = kb.nextLine();

    if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
        secretNumber = easyNumber();
        System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
    } else if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
        secretNumber = mediumNumber();
        System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
    } else if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
        secretNumber = hardNumber();
        System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: local variable are not initialized by default. Use 0 or -1 for primitive and `null` for Object to initialize.

Comment: … and will stay like that if neither of the `if` statements is `true`.

Comment: ...or change the last `if else` to an `else`, but then the user could type in anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `difficulty` is not `E`, `M` or `H`, then the `if` clauses will never be entered. Therefore, the variable `secretNumber` will not be initialized.

**How to fix this?**

- Initialize `secretNumber` when you declare it (is a good practice to initialize before using):

  ```
  int secretNumber = -1; // you can change this value
  ```
- Another alternative is to add an `else` block:

  ```
  } else if (...) {
      ...
  } else {
      secretNumber = -1; // you can change this value
  }
  ```

Comment: It's a primitive, it's always initialized.

Comment: @Jeff Its a local variable.

Comment: @Jeff you are wrong. It is initialized if it's an instance variable.

Comment: Completely missed the fact that it was local.  Reading comprehension poor today...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your title question: **Yes, of course**.
To solve your problem: simply do what the compiler says: initialize the variable:

```
int secretNumber = 0;
```

The compiler complains, because you can't be sure that the user entered one of the three possibilities. If the user entered something else, no value would be assigned to the variable, so you would be using a variable that is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> Local variables are not initialized by default. You have to explicitly initialize it before its first use.

Use 0 or -1 for primitive and `null` for Object to initialize.

You can solve it by adding `else` in the last

```
if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("E")) {
    secretNumber = easyNumber();
    System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
} else if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("M")) {
    secretNumber = mediumNumber();
    System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
} else if (difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("H")) {
    secretNumber = hardNumber();
    System.out.println(" " + secretNumber + " ");
} else {
    secretNumber = 0;//any default value
}
```